# VTK: render concave polygon with vtkDelaunay2D

Tags: python, vtk

I want to render a concave polygon with the use of a vtkDelaunay2D. I've read that it should work with a vtkDelaunay2D, but it doesn't. Why?
Here is the my code:

```
import vtk

points = vtk.vtkPoints()

ls = [
    [5, 5], [-5, 5], [-8, 0], [-5, -5], [5, -5], [2, 0]
]
for x, y in ls:
    points.InsertNextPoint(x, y, 0)

aPolyData = vtk.vtkPolyData()
aPolyData.SetPoints(points)

delaunay = vtk.vtkDelaunay2D()
delaunay.SetInputData(aPolyData)

meshMapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
meshMapper.SetInputConnection(delaunay.GetOutputPort())

colors = vtk.vtkNamedColors()

meshActor = vtk.vtkActor()
meshActor.SetMapper(meshMapper)
meshActor.GetProperty().EdgeVisibilityOn()
meshActor.GetProperty().SetEdgeColor(colors.GetColor3d("Peacock"))
meshActor.GetProperty().SetInterpolationToFlat()

renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renderWindow = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renderWindow.AddRenderer(renderer)
renderWindowInteractor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
renderWindowInteractor.SetRenderWindow(renderWindow)

renderer.AddActor(meshActor)
renderer.SetBackground(colors.GetColor3d("Mint"))

renderWindow.SetSize(640, 480)
renderWindow.Render()
renderWindowInteractor.Start()
```

The result looks like this:

[image: result]

The triangle on the right side shouldn't be there.

So why does this happen? And what do I have to do so this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkDelaunay2D.html#details) (specially the `Warning` part), output is expected to be convex.

As workaround for your example, decreasing the `Offset` value of the filter leads to the result you want (for instance `delaunay.SetOffset(0.1)`). But as it is not intended by the filter, it may have unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

You may add a counterclockwise polydata cotaining the line that defines the boundary using `delaunay.SetSourceData(polyline)`, then you get the desired result:

[image]

but this only works if you assume you know the boundary